# Derivation of Bayes classifier equation

Tags: probability, bayesian, classification, discriminant-analysis

In the Elements of Statistical learning book when introducing Linear Discriminant Analysis it says:

> A simple application of Bayes theorem gives us
>
> $Pr(G=K|X=x) = \frac{f_k(x)\pi_k}{\sum_{l=1}^Kf_l(x)\pi_l}$

where $\pi_k$ is the prior probability of class $k$ and $f_k(x)$ is the class conditional probability.

1. What is the class conditional probability? Is it $Pr(X=x|G=K)$?
2. How is derived the above equation from the Bayes theorem? I know 
   $Pr(G=K|X=x) = \frac{Pr(X=x|G=K)Pr(G=K)}{Pr(X=x)}$

I know that $Pr(G=k)=\pi_k$ but I do not know how to derive the rest of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is the number of classes, we can correct the formula as follows and use lowercase $k$ for referring to a specific class:
$$P(G=k|X=x)=\frac{f_k(x)\pi(x)}{\sum_{l=1}^K f_l(x)\pi_l}$$

The class conditional probability is $P(X=x|G=k)$, or in case of non-discrete RVs class conditional density we use $f(X=x|G=k)$. The derivation follows from your note in (2):
$$P(G=k|X=x)=\frac{\overbrace{P(X=x|G=k)}^{f_k(x)}\overbrace{P(G=k)}^{\pi_k}}{P(X=x)}$$
And, we can expand $P(X=x)$ via Total Probability Theorem:
$$P(X=x)=\sum_{l=1}^K P(X=x|G=l)P(G=l)=\sum_{l=1}^Kf_l(x)\pi_l$$

Comment: RV stands for real-valued?

Comment: Random Variable